# Xubuntu 13.10 unable to connect to router (with internet connectivity) via ethernet

Tags: networking, xubuntu, internet, ethernet

I'm running a MSI B85-G43 gaming motherboard, just got Xubuntu 13.10 and the installation went fine except for connectivity to the router. I've plugged in my ethernet cable from my router to the motherboard, and there are light-up signals on my router and motherboard, however Xubuntu is unable to detect any internet connectivity. I'm not sure if I am missing anything here, would I need to install any drivers for the ethernet? I doubt so as the motherboard is built in with Killer E2200 Ethernet...

I can run any commands if you need more information, but I'm not really sure how to proceed from here...

Thanks and warm regards~

Answer (score 0):

what does `ifconfig` tell you? 
It should give you what IP Address has been assigned to the Ethernet connection.